# iOS - Added Framework, how do I import classes now?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks

I have added a framework to my xcode swift 4.x project.  The framework was built using objective-c, is it not possible to set-up a bridging header w/ frameworks?

How will I be able to import my framework so I can start using its functionality?

Additionally, the project I'm using originally has a public cocoapod, I'm able to do the normal **import PROJECT**.  But I have compiled the source to create a framework w/o the need of cocoapods, I have added the framework to the project, how will I be able to import it now in my swift classes?

Comment: `import {module name}` typically

Comment: It doesn't appear.

Comment: @TimNuwin then you haven’t linked the framework to your target.